# How to use SDCard folder instead of assets folder?

Tags: android, assets

i'm trying to use .jpg images from sdfolder in SDcard instead of assets folder.
i'm still getting the images from the assets folder.
I think the problem is in this line!

```
copy(getAssets().open(filename), new File(path) );
```

Can someone give me some hints?

```
//create a folder in sdcard directory

File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdfolder");

String[] urls = null;
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();


        try {

            //urls = getAssets().list(""); 
            urls = folder.list();

            for (String filename : urls) 
            {
                if (filename.matches(".+\\.jpg")) 
                {
                    String path = getFilesDir() + "/" + filename;
                    copy(getAssets().open(filename), new File(path) );
                    items.add(path);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FilePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new FilePagerAdapter(this, items);
        pagerAdapter.setOnItemChangeListener(new OnItemChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemChange(int currentPosition)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(GalleryFileActivity.this, "Current item is " + currentPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mViewPager = (GalleryViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewer);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


 public void copy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to list the files in a directory of the External Storage, find items by those same names in Assets, and copy them to the Internal Storage... that seems a bit mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Just substitute copy(getAssets().open(filename), new File(path) ); for

copy(new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdfolder/"+filename)),new File(path));

Thank you!